# Why should I use @ngrx/store?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've seen a lot of codes using the @ngrx/store library but I don't really understand why.

Actually, we have the dependency injections doing the same job with storing data for our application. And Angular is natively applying the Flux design pattern for us (unidirectional data flow).

So what's the point about adding some complexity (stores/actions etc.) to our code ?

Comment: Unidirectional data flow alone is not Flux - bear in mind that React also has unidirectional data flow, yet Facebook still saw fit to develop Flux on top of it.

Comment: Oh I didnt know that, thanks for the precision

Comment: Honestly I wish the whole store pattern advocates would just get out of the Angular ecosystem and go to pollute the React would with that overkill.

Comment: Take a look at a library I created out of pure disdain for ngrx. It is called ngx-rxcache. It is a very light weight Behaviour Subject based cache. I have been using it for the last few weeks and I am really happy how it is coming along so far.

https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-rxcache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ngrx/store is a controlled state container designed to help write performant, consistent applications on top of Angular. Core tenets:

State is a single immutable data structure
Actions describe state changes
Pure functions called reducers take the previous state and the next action to compute the new state
State accessed with the Store, an observable of state and an observer of actions

Comment: How can ngrx/store improve my application's performance? I mean, the change detectors in Angular will work the same way, am I wrong?

Comment: Ok my bad, i went on the github's page : "These core principles enable building components that can use the OnPush change detection strategy giving you intelligent, performant change detection throughout your application.".